# Is it possible to scale a text to a certain width by changing font attributes?

Tags: fabricjs

Let me add an image to describe my question.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SisN7.jpg

My facebook name is located at the top-left. It has 9 characters and it is centered on the dark gray block.

Right now, if my name was just "D", it would appear on the place where "D" letter is located. Alternatively, if my nickname was something like "IHaveAVeryLongUsernameWoah", it would overflow to pink area.

Is there any auto-scaling feature on FabricJS, so I can simply define the max-width, and FabricJS calculates font size automatically?

Like, if there is a single letter, print it at the center. If there are alot of letters and letter width exceeds maximum size, then lower font size.

Not sure if this is doable. Any help would be appreciated.